Compute $\lim_{x \to \infty } x(\sqrt{x^2 +2x} -2 \sqrt {x^2 +x} +x)$
Compute $\lim_{x \to \infty } x(\sqrt{x^2 +2x} -2 \sqrt {x^2 +x} +x).$
I tried multiplying both the numerator and the denominator by $\sqrt{x^2 +2x} +2 \sqrt {x^2 +x} +x$ so that it turns to $\lim_{x \to \infty } \frac {-2x(x^2+x-x\sqrt{x^2+2x})}{\sqrt{x^2+2x}+2\sqrt{x^2+x}+x}$. But I don't know how to do next.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344585/prove-lim-x-to-inftyx2-3x11-3-x1-3-1-3

Try factoring $x^2$ out of the two square roots.

You can multiply by another conjugate.  Take the square root part vs the polynomial part

Do you know what a series expansion is? If you do, you could get the answer as soon as you factor the $x^2$ out of the square roots and do the series expansion around $1$.

Starting with
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} x\left(\sqrt{x^2+2x}-2\sqrt{x^2+x}+x\right),
$$
one trick is to multiply by conjugates twice.  There are many conjugates that you could use - one was chosen by the OP, but I'll choose a different one for fun.  I'm going to separate the square root parts and the polynomial part, so I'll multiply the numerator and denominator by
$$
\sqrt{x^2+2x}-2\sqrt{x^2+x}-x.
$$
This gives
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x\left(\sqrt{x^2+2x}-2\sqrt{x^2+x}+x\right)\left(\sqrt{x^2+2x}-2\sqrt{x^2+x}-x\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+2x}-2\sqrt{x^2+x}-x},
$$
which simplifies to
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x\left(4x^2+6x-4\sqrt{x^2+2x}\sqrt{x^2+x}\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+2x}-2\sqrt{x^2+x}-x}.
$$
At this point, we've reduced the numerator to have only one square root, so we try another conjugate, separating the square root part from the polynomial part.  In other words, we'll multiply the numerator and denominator by
$$
4x^2+6x+4\sqrt{x^2+2x}\sqrt{x^2+x}.
$$
This results in
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x\left(4x^2+6x-4\sqrt{x^2+2x}\sqrt{x^2+x}\right)\left(4x^2+6x+4\sqrt{x^2+2x}\sqrt{x^2+x}\right)}{\left(\sqrt{x^2+2x}-2\sqrt{x^2+x}-x\right)\left(4x^2+6x+4\sqrt{x^2+2x}\sqrt{x^2+x}\right)}.
$$
Simplifying, the numerator, we get
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{4x^3}{\left(\sqrt{x^2+2x}-2\sqrt{x^2+x}-x\right)\left(4x^2+6x+4\sqrt{x^2+2x}\sqrt{x^2+x}\right)}.
$$
Since the first factor in the denominator has a highest power of $x$ of $x^1$ and the second factor in the denominator has a highest power of $x$ of $x^2$, we divide the numerator and denominator by $x^3$, distributing across the factors of the denominator to get that this limit is
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{4}{\left(\sqrt{1+2/x}-2\sqrt{1+1/x}-1\right)\left(4+6/x+4\sqrt{1+2/x}\sqrt{1+1/x}\right)}.
$$
Many of the terms in this limit approach zero as $x$ approaches infinity, so we have that this limit is
$$
\frac{4}{\left(\sqrt{1}-2\sqrt{1}-1\right)\left(4+4\sqrt{1}\sqrt{1}\right)}=\frac{4}{(-2)(8)}=-\frac{1}{4}.
$$

After your first step, we can conclude as follows
$$\frac {-2x\left(x^2+x-x\sqrt{x^2+2x}\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+2x}+2\sqrt{x^2+x}+x}=\frac {-2\left(x^2+x-x\sqrt{x^2+2x}\right)}{\sqrt{1+\frac2x}+2\sqrt{1+\frac1x}+1}\to\frac{-2\cdot\frac12}{4}=-\frac14$$
indeed multiplying by conjugate
$$x^2+x-x\sqrt{x^2+2x}=\frac{x^2}{x^2+x+x\sqrt{x^2+2x}}\to \frac12$$

We simplify the expression :
$$ x \left( \sqrt{x^2+2x} - 2\sqrt{x^2+x} + x \right) = x^2 \left(  \sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}} -2\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}} + 1 \right) $$
We will use a series expansion :
\begin{align}
\underset{x \longrightarrow +\infty}{\text{lim}} x \left( \sqrt{x^2+2x} - 2\sqrt{x^2+x} + x \right) &= \underset{x \longrightarrow +\infty}{\text{lim}} x^2 \left(  \sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}} -2\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}} + 1 \right) \\
&=\underset{x \longrightarrow +\infty}{\text{lim}} x^2 \left( 1+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2x^2} -2-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{4x^2}+1+o \left( \frac{1}{x^2} \right)   \right) \\
&=\underset{x \longrightarrow +\infty}{\text{lim}} x^2 \left( -\frac{1}{4x^2} + o \left( \frac{1}{x^2} \right)   \right) \\
&= \underset{x \longrightarrow +\infty}{\text{lim}}  -\frac{1}{4} + o(1) \\
&=-\frac{1}{4}
\end{align}

When you see such differences of root expressions while $x\to \infty$, the substitution $x=\frac 1t$ with $t\to 0^+$ can be quite helpful:
$$\sqrt{x^2 +2x} +2 \sqrt {x^2 +x} +x \stackrel{x=\frac 1t}{=}\frac{\sqrt{1+2t}-2\sqrt{1+t}+1}{t^2}$$
Now, L'Hospital does the rest:
$$\frac{\sqrt{1+2t}-2\sqrt{1+t}+1}{t^2}\stackrel{L'Hosp}{\sim}\underbrace{\frac 1{\sqrt{1+2t}\sqrt{1+t}}}_{\stackrel{t\to 0^+}{\rightarrow}1}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{1+t} - \sqrt{1+2t}}{2t}$$
$$\frac{\sqrt{1+t} - \sqrt{1+2t}}{2t}\stackrel{L'Hosp}{\sim}\frac{\frac 1{2\sqrt{1+t}} - \frac 1{\sqrt{1+2t}}}{2}\stackrel{t\to 0^+}{\longrightarrow}-\frac 14$$

In the following elementary solution we avoid multiplying long expressions (n morę than two summands).
Let $$ a=x^{-1}[\sqrt{x^2+2x}+\sqrt{x^2+x}] =\sqrt{1+2x^{-1}}+\sqrt{1+x^{-1}}\\ b=x^{-1}[\sqrt{x^2+x}+x]=\sqrt{1+x^{-1}} +1$$
Then
$$\sqrt{x^2+2x}-\sqrt{x^2+x}= a^{-1}\\
-\sqrt{x^2+x}+x=-b^{-1}$$  The expression under the limit sign is equal $$x(a^{-1}-b^{-1})=a^{-1}b^{-1}(xb-xa)  =a^{-1}b^{-1}(x-\sqrt{x^2+2x} )\\ =a^{-1}b^{-1}{-2x\over x+\sqrt{x^2+2x}}=a^{-1}b^{-1}{-2\over 1+\sqrt{1+2x^{-1}}}$$ As $a\to 2$ and $b\to 2$ the limit is equal $2^{-1}2^{-1}(-2)2^{-1}=-4^{-1}.$
